# Problem Reading Data using FTDI D2xx library

Tags: android, ftdi, d2xx

I am trying for MODBUS RTU communication using FTDI usb to serial driver / library d2xx. I can see the message being sent from my android app on my pc and my desktop pc does sends me the message back. I am successfully getting required amount of bytes but i am receiving all "0" from FT_Device.read() method.

Any help would be of greatly appreciated.

I have written android code...

```
package com.example.ftdilib;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ftdi.j2xx.D2xxManager;
import com.ftdi.j2xx.FT_Device;

import java.sql.Driver;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private TextView tv;

    private Context mMe;
    private D2xxManager mManager;
    private FT_Device mDevice;
    private D2xxManager.DriverParameters mDriverParameters;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

        mMe = getApplicationContext();

        try {
            mManager = D2xxManager.getInstance(mMe);
        } catch (D2xxManager.D2xxException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mMe, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        initButton();
    }

    private void initButton() {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(mManager != null)
                {
                    int devCount = mManager.createDeviceInfoList(mMe);
                    if(devCount > 0)
                    {
                        mDriverParameters = new D2xxManager.DriverParameters();
                        mDriverParameters.setBufferNumber(2);
                        mDriverParameters.setMaxTransferSize(1024);
                        mDriverParameters.setReadTimeout(250);

                        mDevice = mManager.openByIndex(mMe, 0, mDriverParameters);

                        if(mDevice != null)
                        {
                            if(mDevice.isOpen())
                            {
                                mDevice.setBaudRate(9600);
                                mDevice.setDataCharacteristics(D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8, D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1, D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE);
                                mDevice.restartInTask();

                                mRunner = new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        getData();
                                        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunner, 50);
                                    }
                                };

                                mHandler.post(mRunner);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mMe, "NO DEVICE FOUND.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getData()
    {
        byte[] _req =  getHoldingRegisters((byte)1,(int)0, (int)4);
    }

    private byte[] getHoldingRegisters(byte slaveid, int startingaddress, int quantity)
    {
        byte[] _msg = new byte[8];
        _msg[0] = slaveid;
        _msg[1] = 3;
        _msg[2] = (byte) (startingaddress >> 8);
        _msg[3] = (byte) (startingaddress & 0xFF);
        _msg[4] = (byte) (quantity >> 8);
        _msg[5] = (byte) (quantity & 0xFF);
        int crc = getCRC(_msg);

        _msg[6] = (byte) (crc & 0xFF);
        _msg[7] = (byte) (crc >> 8);

        mDevice.write(_msg, _msg.length);

        byte[] _req = new byte[5 + (quantity*2)];

        int available = mDevice.getQueueStatus();

        setText(tv, String.valueOf(available));

        mDevice.read(_req, _req.length, 250);

        return null;
    }

    private int getCRC(byte[] input) {
        int iPos = 0; // loop position in input buffer
        int crc = 0xFFFF;
        while (iPos < input.length - 2) {
            crc ^= (input[iPos] & 0xFF);
            iPos++;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                boolean bitOne = ((crc & 0x1) == 0x1);
                crc >>>= 1;
                if (bitOne) {
                    crc ^= 0x0000A001;
                }
            }
        }

        return crc;
    }

    private void setText(final TextView textView, final String value)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the absolute minimum reproducable example if you are asking for help. This increases the chance to identify the issue and get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was compilling the project using Android SDK 28 i.e. for Android 9 and i was having Android 6 on my mobile and table. Later i installed it in Android 9 on my friend's mobile and it worked like charm..

Comment: Yes... I am new to android studio and android. I was unaware of this fact.